# Passing a object to jQuery .each() (instead a function) causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my JavaScript code, and it give me some weird errors:

```
    $(".jchart div").each({
      $(this).css({
        'height': jBarHeight
      });
    });
```

This code gives me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` on the line `$(this).css({`

I also tried this:

```
    $(".jchart").find("div").each({
      $(this).css({
        'height': jBarHeight
      });
    });
```

But it gives me the same exact error, what could be the problem!?

Also note:
`jBarHeight`is a defined variable somewhere else in the code I didn't post, I cut out a lot of code to reduce the question size.

Comment: `.each()` takes a function as its argument, not an object.

Comment: Note: the reason it is giving you that error is because it is trying to use `$(this).css({` as a field on an object.

Comment: @jsve Yeah, sorry, after doing the same thing repeatedly I guess my brain just wanted to do it "the short way", which was also the wrong way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes a callback function, not an object.

Try this:

```
$(".jchart").find("div").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'height': jBarHeight
    });
});
```

Comment: It's always good to have someone else review your code, after a while of doing the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already had it explained to you why your `.each()` call didn't work (it requires a callback function as an argument).

But, as it turns out, there is no need for `.each()` here at all.  You can just do this:

```
$(".jchart div").height(jBarHeight);
```

And, jQuery will iterate all the elements in the collection and call `.height()` on them.  If you wanted to use `.css()` instead, you could do this:

```
$(".jchart div").css("height", jBarHeight);
```

or

```
$(".jchart div").css({height: jBarHeight});
```

All of these are simpler than doing your own `.each()` iteration and take advantage of the fact that most jQuery methods that apply some change to the jQuery collection will iterate the whole collection for you automatically.

Comment: Actually, `.each()` does have a use, I just forgot to include the variable inside it. Because `jBarHeight` is getting the data from each `data-jc-height` which they are all different.

Comment: OK, the best we can do is advise you based on the info you put in your question.  I haven't figured out how to channel that ESP thing yet.  Oh well, I guess I wasted my time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wanted the first line to read:

```
$(".jchart div").each(function(){
```

Without the `function()` you are declaring an object literal, not a function, and so the `(` in `$(this)` is illegal.